# Google map myLocation button color after tracking user current location - ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

In Google map ios app i find location button like this when it is not tapped for current location 
[image: Before tapping]

After tapping on myLocation button it is like this (blue color).Location button.not the dot.
[image: After getting current location]

How i can make this in my ios App? Help please
Want this [image: blue tint] now this [image: gray tint]
After and before finding current location

Comment: Render the image of the button and keep changing the Tint Color accordingly

Comment: there is no tint or color property for this button 
self.googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton.

Answer (score 0):

First you get your current location using below code -

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation = self.mapView.myLocation.coordinate;
```

Then you may use GMSMarker to point your current location with image or color

```
 GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
   // marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"point1.png"]; 
    marker.map = self.mapView;
```

Hope above code will be help you.

Comment: No .i don't want to set marker on my current location.i just want this above feature of google map ios app in my application.the location button color when it find current location just as the Google map app.

Comment: Please add [mapView_ addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:NULL];
Then call self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES; under - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context

Comment: Not working. Tapping on myLocation button animating camera to current location but myLocation button color is same as before.